# How to get the data from the console output of API through Angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular, api

I am currently working on a full stack project using asp.net and angularjs.I have written this code to get output response from the Swagger API.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyIE.png)
I have done the API designing through ASP. Net.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQkHS.png)

I want to know how I can fetch the details under "data". What should be the code for this?

`Please help me with the code to display the details under "data" in the response i.e., id, created Date etc.`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would define a variable that is equal to the response data as such

```
const data = successResponse.data;
```

then you could map over the data using `data.map(val => { // do something with the value  })`

Or you could run a for loop, or execute the forEach method.